# how to get the next part of the facebook response feed when using graph api ?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to get friendlists from facebook graph api but the i am not able to exactly find how to use the "next" pagination link that the api response contains .

```
FB.api(
            '/me',
            'GET',
            {"fields":"friends,friendlists"},
            function(response) {
                // Insert your code here
                console.log(response) ; 
            }
          );
```

Here's how I called the api.

This is the response :

```
data:{
somedata
}
paging:{
next:"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/341589523008760/friendlists?access_token=EAAFsRERab38BAFOOzLdZBUp7QOQuKebY98TiMNg2ZAodT6MSWpPaMFhg4QXPMQLJZBZCYMoAwfn8Dwq0TMZAYUskWo3ZBzsGlA8fNAtbINoZA4p2wqXrTsODPXR0XnxI2VIRRHLdSdktbQDAcPya2dhSWbtku74ZCb8CRhZADxw7hVBd7cmD0ySdeMnZB6CsW0l7ZBdrqJSXbZBiXAZDZD&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_AdD0bVtB2CkUfZBZAuUEMK99EPxHE0UVoeX2lZAdsrus7K7CTpC4L8XVxLbv84fLxwxhaAZBtqZAv2bIDHsf192ZBhSmZAv"
}
```

I looked into their docs but they haven't mentioned any example or code on how to use this "next" pagination .

Comment: You just do `FB.api(response.data.paging.next, 'GET', ...)`, where `next` is the URL there.

Comment: ohh will try it , please post this as an answer :) thnaks

Comment: You may have to cut out the `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12` bit, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 types of pagination ..

- Cursor-based Pagination
- Time-based Pagination
- Offset-based Pagination

I prefear to use Offset-based Pagination .

*" Offset pagination can be used when you do not care about chronology and just want a specific number of objects returned. This should only be used if the edge does not support cursor or time-based pagination. "*

An offset-paginated edge supports the following parameters:

- offset : This offsets the start of each page by the number specified.
- limit : This is the maximum number of objects that may be returned. A query may return fewer than the value of limit due to filtering. Do not depend on the number of results being fewer than the limit value to indicate your query reached the end of the list of data, use the absence of next instead as described below. For example, if you set limit to 10 and 9 results are returned, there may be more data available, but one item was removed due to privacy filtering. Some edges may also have a maximum on the limit value for performance reasons. In all cases, the API returns the correct pagination links.
- next : The Graph API endpoint that will return the next page of data. If not included, this is the last page of data. Due to how pagination works with visibility and privacy, it is possible that a page may be empty but contain a 'next' paging link. Stop paging when the 'next' link no longer appears.
- previous : The Graph API endpoint that will return the previous page of data. If not included, this is the first page of data.

Its great, try it .

If need i can find some example ..

*Editing*
Including sample 
PROMPT for offset and limit, so you can test it.

```
    var offset = prompt("Offset", "0");
    var limite = prompt("Limite", "25");
    var username = id; 
FB.api('/v2.4/'+id+'/feed?fields=id,object_id,message,from,to,picture,type,likes.limit(25){id},shares,created_time,comments.limit(50),full_picture,link,caption,name,story,description&offset='+offset+'&limit=25&callback=', function(response) {
    limit = 50;
     var i = 0;
       jQuery.each(response.data, function ()
```

So here you can handle data as your needs .
I used this sometime ago, i think need update .
This used in a app that creates all Feed from a group.. 
Variable set inside the call offset='+offset+'&limit=25

So this could get 25 "messages" (from group id) changing offset, to get next part of response .
I do the same for likes, comments, inside the call :
comments.limit(50)

I think its better put offset='+offset+'&limit=25 variables in the end of the call .

I could help better if could see your code .

Comment: Ya an example with regard the above context will be helpful. Please provide it.

Comment: Done! Its the best option, for me, it takes some time to update it, sample isnt full. I tired answer and geting downvotes from those who are not looking for help .